# C# How to detect splitted file type?

Tags: c#, file, winrar

I tried to split a large file into many small files by WINRAR or win-zip or any split-er program.

I want to know each file types, even file name changed to unknown format.

Is it possible to read property descriptions of files to detect file type or find other parts?

how can i do that?

Comment: Is checking the extension will determine your file types?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know which rar is first in multi rar archives using SevenZipSharp/Unrar in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317316/how-to-know-which-rar-is-first-in-multi-rar-archives-using-sevenzipsharp-unrar-i)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really tell the file type without reading it context, because a file extension can be renamed.
If extension is good enough for you, you can use

```
Path.GetExtension(filename)
```

If you want to dive deeper to the real file type you should check: 
https://www.filesignatures.net/

This site will give you the signature byte array, that each file of that type will start with. You can read the file byte array and compare it to the type you would like to get.